# ROW_NUMBER function in sqlite3 module

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, discord

I am using the sqlite3 module within node.js to create and interact with an sqlite database, and am trying to work with the ROW_NUMBER function, but I can't quite seem to get it to work and was wondering if perhaps that function even exists within sqlite same as it does in SQL.

```
    client.db.each('SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY guildbank DESC LIMIT 10) rownum, guildname, guildbank FROM guilds', [], (err, row1) => {
    if(err) {
        console.error(err.message)
    }
    if(row1.guildname == message.guild.name) istopten = true
    embed.addField(`${row1.rownum}. ${row1.guildname}`, `has ${row1.guildbank} yen in their guild bank!`)
    if(istopten) {
        client.db.each('SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY guildbank) rownum, guildname, guildbank FROM guilds', [], (err, row2) => {
            if(err) {
                console.error(err.message)
            }
            if(row2.guildname == message.guild.name) embed.setFooter(`Your guild is in `)
        })
    }
})
```

The error I am getting is referencing that there is no guildname property of row1 and I have came to the conclusion that my query is the cause of the error. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

```
SQLITE_ERROR: near "LIMIT": syntax error
C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\projects\yabe-reworked\Coding-Yabe-Sei\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\trace.js:27
                    throw err;
                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'guildname' of undefined
    at client.db.each (C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\projects\yabe-reworked\Coding-Yabe-Sei\commands\economy\leaderboard.js:11:17)
```

is the relevant part of the error

Comment: the table and its names are all set up properly, I know that is important

Comment: What, if any, is the error message, and does it complain about `ROW_NUMBER` not being a valid function?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Relevant part of error edited in, thanks for pointing out that I oughta do that

Comment: These look to be JavaScript errors, which, however, does not mean that your SQL is valid.  To test for valid SQL, try running directly against SQLite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumb mistake by me that I honestly should've known better, can't put the LIMIT 10 within the ROW_NUMBER function, you have to put it at the end of the query. Thanks for the ideas :)